# parent of root - remembering Apollo/Domain OS

Tags: file-sharing

Decades ago I worked in a lab equipped with Apollo/Domain workstations. One of the niceties of these machines was that their filesystems where organised and accessible as directories in what appeared to be the parent of an individual machine's root directory. You accessed that "super root" with `//`; your home directory would be `//$HOST/$HOME`.

It would be really nice to have such an automatic networked filesystem at home. Is there any software that does something similar (for Linux & Mac)?

EDIT: as an example of something I don't see how you'd do it with the protocols mentioned below, here's something a bit sneaky I used to do:

- Set up a directory of mine in a writable portion of fast harddisk space on the fastest machine on the LAN, IIRC something like `mkdir -p //fysae/tmp/.bertin/home`, copy login scripts and work stuff there, and then `setenv HOME "//fysae/tmp/.bertin/home"` (this is also where I picked up my addition to [t]csh). All that was done with shell commands which is also where I did all my work. BTW, another nice feature made all this more transparent; it was possible to reference an env. variable in symlinks so their target depended on that variable.

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty much what the CIFS addressing scheme allows for. So, yeah, that works, based on samba.

The same can be achieved with sshfs mounts or NFS mounts, too.

So, yes, that is commonly seen.

Comment: I know the way MS Windows networking works (or worked?) with a very similar `\\host\path\to\something` scheme. I've always wondered if they didn't borrow the concept from Domain/OS, but I'm not aware that this has been integrated at the system level elsewhere. Unless I'm mistaken one could do `fopen("//host/path/to/something","r")` on Domain/OS and it worked - and that's what I was asking about. The CIFS/sshfs/NFS approaches I know all require either mounting the share somewhere under `/` or the use of high-level code that knows how to handle paths like "ssh://user@host:/path/to/somewhere".

Comment: Note the authentication step, which was implicit on Domain/OS as accounts where shared among machines too (YellowPages?).

Comment: yeah, high-level code such as Windows implements in their kernel abstraction userland library (canonical Windows paths look different than one thinks). Such exist for Linux as well – GIO, KIO, others. Try it! Open your Gnome/cinnamon/KDE text editor and type in an ssh:// url :D

Comment: But yeah, this is why I change my UID on every new system I set up so it matches the one on my Mac, which is well under the usual 1001 Linux attributes to the first non-root user.

Comment: that sounds like something you'd usually solve via ID mapping, instead.

Comment: regarding common auth: very standard both in the Windows and Linux world to implement that via ActiveDirectory/kerberos (on linux, using SSSD). Your ID-granting ticket then can be used for SMB mounts, NFS mounts, SSH login, HTTP auth, …

Comment: Maybe, but chancing the ID on a newly created account is trivial and can't break somewhere down the road ;)

Comment: @RJVB YellowPages (NIS) was from Sun. Domain/OS implemented a replicated (distributed) registry system on top of its Network Computing System (NCS) which was presented to the system as a read-only /etc/passwd file. This was, for a short time, released as a separate product, by HP I think, called **/etc/passwd**, for heterogenous networks, similar to Sun NIS. It made the use of the network root // easy to implement and use. I think Apollo used **The Computer is the Network** during some advertising at the time, predating Suns **The Network is the Computer**, although ICBM.

Comment: I just had a short discussion with CMake devs regarding how they handle a leading double slash in one situation. They also claimed that Linux can be set up to interpret it like MSWin interprets a leading `\\`. Didn't say how though...